# How to pass a function as parameter of another function in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, std

I'm trying to build a class made up by a vector of threads.
The class should have a method that take as argument another function, this function has to be executed by a new threads.
I would like to avoid use of native pointer, so I'm not excatly sure how to build this specific method.

Comment: Your two options are basically passing a function pointer or a `std::function`

Comment: Or a template, so you can accept either (and lambdas) without `std::function` overhead.

Comment: Do you need a pool of threads? I mean a function should be executed on one of the existing threads? Or you need to start new thread every time a function is posted?

Comment: i need to start a new one, each time the method is invoked.
So basicaly the prototype of this method should be something like: 
...
void add_task( const std::function<T> & f );
...
Right?

Comment: @HakimLaxe, if so, you can straightforwardly use std::thread constructor. [cpp ref link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) . I guess (3) costructor is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Also you can create a function with the prototype that looks like (3) constructor and perfect forward the arguments of your function into the (3) constructor.

Comment: FYI: You can't _really_ pass a function. Functions in C++ are not values that can be stored in variables. When we say "pass a function," that's actually a lazy way of saying, "pass a _pointer to_ a function," or "pass a [_functional object_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object_)."

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function like this:

```
template <typename F>
void call_function(F f) {
    f();
}
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void sayHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}


int main() {
    call_function(sayHello);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i just have a simple question about that.
What about if I've to invoke different function that has different argument lists, such as:
...
void displayNum(int n){std::cout << n << std::endl; }
void displayArray( int v[], int size){
for( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )  
 std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
...

Answer (score 0):

regarding your constraints I suggest to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). You can then use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and if using C++20, [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front).

cheers,
FM.